# shower water either hot or cold; not mixing; valve/ cartridge/ plumbing?

Tags: shower, valve, cartridge

In my rental unit, the shower [no tub, just shower] faucet is completely goofed up.  It's a 1 handle faucet. The hot and cold water don't mix.  If it was a clock, 'off' is 12:00. Turn counter clockwise to 11, 10, 9:00, the water is cold. The handle won't go past, say, 9 or 8:00.  Turn clockwise back to 12:00, it's off.  Turn it clockwise to 1:00 2:00, 3:00; it's HOT. I't won't turn past about 4:00 or so.  There's no way to get warm water. Hot and cold are opposite each other; you can get only 1 or the other.  My last tenant never complained about it, but my new tenant can't get it a comfortable temperature, and I can't figure it out either.  Anybody??  Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure that there is no on/off function, such as pulling the handle?

Comment: There's no additional moving part; the handle goes either clockwise, or counter clockwise; off is at 12:00. It's an inexpensive faucet.  That having been said, it would be just like me to overlook the obvious...

Answer (score 1):

The cartridge inside the shower body may be shot. Call a plumber and have him inspect it, if you don't know how to change one. They're relatively easy to do. remove the handle, remove the housing, pull out the cartridge. reassemble...

Comment: Thanks for your response!  Does it seem more like a bad cartridge, or a bad plumber? I'm pretty sure it was installed this way... would there have been a way to install it incorrectly that would make it work this way?

Comment: doubt it would have been able to be assembled if it was installed wrong. could be upside down, but i doubt the housing would have screwed on. if you handy you can give it a shot. don't forget to shut off the water first.

Answer (score 1):

FIGURED IT OUT!!
Thank you to those who answered- I appreciate your willingness to help!
The handle was put on in the wrong position!
I took it off and rotated it [pretty sure it was 180 degrees].  This made it so that when starting at 6:00, turning counterclockwise, it started with cold water, then continued to turn freely to get warmer, finally hot.  I'm so glad it was a simple fix.  Sometimes there is a free lunch!

Comment: You should mark you answer as THE answer.  (Congratulations on your solution and thanks for sharing!).